# typescript: overwrite a field from an extended interface

Tags: typescript, interface

I've got an interface which extends 2 other interfaces.

The new interface is identical except for one thing: the field '_id' should be a string instead of an ObjectId  (for easier server side operations).

Is it possible to overwrite the type of a field in the new interface? When I do it, tslint tells the new interface doesn't extend properly the previous ones.

Also I'd like to avoid union type such as: `_id : ObjectId | string`

```
export interface AchievementDb {
    _id: ObjectID; 
    title: string;
    description: string;
    // more stuff
}

export interface AchievementUserProgress {
    _id: ObjectID;
    progress: number;
    status: UserAchievementStatus;
    // more stuff
}

export interface AchievementFull extends AchievementDb, AchievementUserProgress {
    _id: string;
}
```

Comment: What you want to achieve will not be possible because all types should be better strictly defined. That's why the interface is defined to help you and others to not violate some contract rules. And you are violating the "Interface segregation principle" from SOLID principles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several options.

We could use a generic type parameter on the interfaces to specify the type of `id`. We can specify a default type parameter to be able to keep using the interface without type parameters if necessary:

```
export interface AchievementDb<T = ObjectID> {
  _id: T; 
  title: string;
  description: string;
  // more stuff
}
export interface AchievementUserProgress<T = ObjectID> {
  _id: T;
  progress: number;
  status: UserAchievementStatus;
  // more stuff
}

export interface AchievementFull extends AchievementDb<string>, AchievementUserProgress<string> {
}
```

Another option is to use `Pick` and `Exclude` to remove the field from the interfaces so we can override it as we wish (you will find a similar type defined as `Omit` by others)

```
type ExcludeId<T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, '_id'>>
export interface AchievementFull extends ExcludeId<AchievementDb>, ExcludeId<AchievementUserProgress> {
  _id: string;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I would see two options:

## Base interfaces

```
interface WithID {
    _id: ObjectID;
}

interface AchievementDbBase {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    // more stuff
}

interface AchievementDb extends AchievementDbBase, WithID {

}

interface AchievementUserProgressBase {
    progress: number;
    // more stuff
}

interface AchievementUserProgress extends AchievementUserProgressBase, WithID {

}

interface AchievementFull extends AchievementDbBase, AchievementUserProgressBase {
    _id: string;
}
```

## Use Omit

Have a look at Exclude Types (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) permitting this kind of mappings for types : 
http://ideasintosoftware.com/typescript-advanced-tricks/

in your case:

```
interface AchievementFull extends Omit<AchievementDb, '_id'>, Omit<AchievementUserProgress, '_id'>  {
    _id: string;
}
```

Comment: How do i omit more than one field from the same type

Answer (score 2):

Based on few other answers, I think this is cleaner (types based on my real code):

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

interface HTMLEvent<T> extends Omit<Event, 'target'> {
    target: T;
}
```

I'm using this type for Angular events so I don't need to cast type of target like in [docs](https://angular.io/guide/user-input):

```
onKey(event: KeyboardEvent) { // with type info
    this.values += (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value + ' | ';
}
```

and use this:

```
onInput(event: HTMLEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
   this.value = event.target.value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are trying to overwrite the field type in `AchievementFull` interface is a sign of a code smell and defeats the purpose of extending the other interfaces. You can't change `_id` type from `ObjectID` to `string` in a child interface.
Maybe you should consider organising your interfaces differently.

TypeScript doesn't allow you to overwrite parent interface property in a child interface.

Comment: While I don't agree you can't do it you are right about it being a code smell :)

Comment: You're right, your solution with generic type param is actually quite readable.